# Rails dockerized: Continuous delivery using Gitlab and Digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, gitlab-ci

I'm actually trying to setup continuous delivery for a Rails dockerized project, hosted on Gitlab.com. I followed [this article](https://medium.com/@codingfriend/continuous-integration-and-deployment-with-gitlab-docker-compose-and-digitalocean-6bd6196b502a) which is not directly related to Rails environment, and that I tried to adapt... Obviously without any success :(

For the context, I created three different services: `db`, `webpacker` and `app`.

Following the above article, here are my **.gitlab-ci.yml** and **docker-compose.staging2.yml** (autodeploy):

```
image: docker
services:
  - docker:dind

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  CONTAINER_CURRENT_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  CONTAINER_LATEST_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
  CONTAINER_STABLE_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:stable

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - release
  - deploy

before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  - apk add --no-cache py-pip python-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make
  - pip install docker-compose
  - docker-compose --version

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose build --pull
    # Here we will run tests when available...
  after_script:
    - docker-compose down
    - docker volume rm `docker volume ls -qf dangling=true`

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t $CONTAINER_CURRENT_IMAGE . --pull
    - docker push $CONTAINER_CURRENT_IMAGE

release-latest-image:
  stage: release
  only:
    - feat-dockerisation
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_CURRENT_IMAGE
    - docker tag $CONTAINER_CURRENT_IMAGE $CONTAINER_LATEST_IMAGE
    - docker push $CONTAINER_LATEST_IMAGE

release-stable-image:
  stage: release
  only:
    - feat-dockerisation
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_CURRENT_IMAGE
    - docker tag $CONTAINER_CURRENT_IMAGE $CONTAINER_STABLE_IMAGE
    - docker push $CONTAINER_STABLE_IMAGE

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - feat-dockerisation
  environment: production
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$DEPLOY_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - which ssh-agent || (apk add openssh-client)
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H $DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - scp -rp ./docker-compose.staging2.yml root@${DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP}:~/
    - ssh root@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker login -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${CI_REGISTRY};
      docker-compose -f docker-compose.staging2.yml down;
      docker pull $CONTAINER_LATEST_IMAGE;
      docker-compose -f docker-compose.staging2.yml up -d"
```

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

  webpacker:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/soykje/beweeg-ror:latest
    command: [sh, -c, "yarn && bin/webpack-dev-server"]
    ports:
      - 3035:3035

  app:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/soykje/beweeg-ror:latest
    links:
      - db
      - webpacker
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

I'm getting started with Docker and CI/CD so... Can't find what I am doing wrong :/

After all the jobs are successfully completed on Gitlab CI/CD, when I try to access my app on the Docker droplet I get nothing... When I ssh on my droplet, everything seems ok, but I still cannot browse anything... Would anyone have an idea of what I am missing?

I feel I'm pretty close to achieve (maybe I'm wrong too...), so any help would be very welcome!

Thx in advance!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Uh sorry, maybe I was not so clear... So my problem is that after all my tasks are completed, when I go to the droplet address (using my browser), I don't get anything... So at this point, I'm not sure what I have done with this article :/

Comment: Add some log because it is hard to say that you might or might not do something wrong; otherwise, sorry, hard to *answer* your problem.

Comment: Well... using my method the only container is the one for the database, as the other are images only... So can't get logs, I guess? :/

Comment: I just updated my question... Maybe it would be more clear this time? Thx in advance

Comment: You don't have `webpack-dev-server` in your `node_modules` path. So, please run `yarn install` before `rails assets:precompile`

Comment: You were right @BerkhanBerkdemir, thank you! I missed that... Now the last problem is that I have for my webpack container a command, such as : `yarn && bin/webpack-dev-server`... For development I defined a start_webpack_dev.sh, but as I'm only copying the docker-compose file in my droplet, it doesn't work... And also same problem event if I copy the sh file too... :/
I guess I should call my commands directly in the docker-compose, but can't find how to make this work?! Maybe an idea? Thx

Comment: I succeed (apparently) in adding the command, using: `command: [sh, -c, "yarn && bin/webpack-dev-server"` :) But, for some reason, still timeout on my droplet... I checked the containers logs and everything seems working. I tried using <my-droplet-ip> and <my-droplet-ip>:3000, but still nothing... Any idea of what I could be doing wrong? Thank you again!

Comment: First, update your question, and after that we can check it out.

Comment: Hello again, and sorry for late response... As I exceeded Gitlab shared runners use limits, I tried to make my own, but pipeline fails everytime now^^ Feel free to help, I'll be back here asap : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812204/switch-from-shared-to-dedicated-gitlab-runner-pipeline-broken Thx

Comment: @BerkhanBerkdemir My previous issue (with dedicated runner) seemed to be DO related... Now it seems to work^^ So I updated my question as asked. Hope you'll be able to help me solve this problem! Thx again